# What is the frequentist take on the voltmeter story?

Tags: likelihood, frequentist

What is the frequentist take on the voltmeter story and its variations? The idea behind it is that a statistical analysis that appeals to hypothetical events would have to be revised if it was later learned that those hypothetical events could not have taken place as assumed.

The [version of the story on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood_principle#The_voltmeter_story) is provided below.

> An engineer draws a random sample of electron tubes and measures their
>   voltage. The measurements range from 75 to 99 volts. A statistician
>   computes the sample mean and a confidence interval for the true mean.
>   Later the statistician discovers that the voltmeter reads only as far
>   as 100, so the population appears to be 'censored'. This necessitates
>   a new analysis, if the statistician is orthodox. However, the engineer
>   says he has another meter reading to 1000 volts, which he would have
>   used if any voltage had been over 100. This is a relief to the
>   statistician, because it means the population was effectively
>   uncensored after all. But, the next day the engineer informs the
>   statistician that this second meter was not working at the time of the
>   measuring. The statistician ascertains that the engineer would not
>   have held up the measurements until the meter was fixed, and informs
>   him that new measurements are required. The engineer is astounded.
>   "Next you'll be asking about my oscilloscope".

The story is obviously meant to be silly but it's not clear to me what liberties are being taken with the methodology it pokes fun at. I'm sure in this case a busy applied statistician wouldn't worry over this but what about a hardcore academic frequentist?

Using a dogmatic frequentist approach, would we need to repeat the experiment? Could we draw any conclusions from the already available data?

To also address the more general point made by the story, if we want to make use of the data  we already have, could the needed revision of hypothetical outcomes be made to fit in the frequentist framework?

Comment: The frequentist approach also allows for conditioning so I am uncertain the reasoning found in the quote is fully adequate.

Comment: @Xi'an Even if we incorporated censoring of the sample or probability of the second voltmeter being broken in our calculations there's the issue that we're *changing the experiment design after it took place*. I don't know if that can be reconciled with frequentist methods.

Comment: Maybe check this entry on the [Conditionality Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditionality_principle). While not a frequentist, I am not a big fan of this story because it seems to imply integrating over all possible hypothetical events without defining the range of those. This is rather caricaturesque.

Comment: This is indeed worthy of thoughtful discussion and answers. But please note that "if the statistician is orthodox" *and not incompetent or greedy for additional work* she will state that since none of the original observations were censored, her original choice of procedure (presumably admissible) *remains admissible* and therefore there is no basis to change it. The theoretical basis that underpins "Frequentist" statistics--decision theory--has no use for this "likelihood principle."

Comment: I know what I would do, provided there is enough data. I would make a histogram. I would look at the histogram. If there was a clear bound at 99 making a one-sided truncated histogram at that point, I would be suspect that it was truncated. I would also look at data known not to be truncated and inspect their curve shapes, and see if I can get a probability model to fit that, e.g., a gamma distribution, or what not. I would then go back to the truncated data (by assumption) and see if the rest of it is also gamma distributed (or whatever). Then I need to explain, "Why gamma?" If so, I am done.

Comment: I believe the likelihood function contains the relevant information and it won't change after discovering data was/wasn't censored. You may argue I believe in the LP but that's not true, when you consider the simplistic likelihood function often taken for granted: that of an iid experiment with n fixed beforehand. This ignores the generating process might be part of a complex experiment. Mayo (2001) argues that incorporating this aspect into the likelihood function won't agree with the usual understanding of the LP. I think she's right, so I don't adhere to the LP so understood.

Comment: Nevertheless I think a carefully defined model taking note of both the "real world" and the experiment would yield a likelihood summarizing the available information. Otherwise, it's like looking at the urn but not at the guy picking the balls from it. That said, in the example of the voltmeter, the same likelihood will work in both scenarios, so the available information will be the same. No new experiment is necessary.

Comment: Isn't the statistician using a frequentist approach just concerned with the calculation of a x%-confidence interval, such that he is right x% of the time? It doesn't matter him if he is wrong or right in the particular case (which he says is either p=0 or p=1). That differentiates with if he uses a Bayesian expression with probabilities in terms of believe. Given this difference. Why would he be upset about the revelation that the test was different? He can adjust his x%-confidence interval accordingly, such that he is again (given the hypothesis the test is correct) right in x% of the time.

Comment: This account of the problem implicitly assumes that the "orthodox reanalysis" would produce a different result than the original analysis.  I believe it would not, if it were correctly done, for the simple reason that the *data* are not censored.  Thus, the burden is on Wikipedia (or Edwards, or Pratt, who is credited with the original story) to provide a plausible and correct classical analysis (accounting for all the relevant information) in which the estimates or the confidence intervals would differ.

Answer (score 8):

In [frequentist inference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequentist_inference), we want to determine how frequently something would have happened if a ***given*** stochastic process were repeatedly realized. That is the starting point for the theory of p-values, confidence intervals, and the like. However, in many applied projects, the "given" process is not really given, and the statistician has to do at least some work specifying and modeling it. This can be a surprisingly ambiguous problem, as it is in this case.

## Modeling the Data Generation Process

Based on the information given, our best candidate seems to be the following:

1. If the 100V meter reads 100V, the engineer re-measures with the 1000V meter *if it is operational.* Otherwise, he simply marks 100V and moves on.

But isn't this a bit unfair to our engineer? Assuming he is an engineer and not merely a technician, he probably understands why he needs to re-measure when the first meter reads 100V; it's because the meter is *saturated* at the upper limit of its range, hence no longer reliable. So perhaps what the engineer would really do is

2. If the 100V meter reads 100, the engineer re-measures with the 1000V meter *if it is operational.* Otherwise, he simply marks 100V, appends a plus sign to indicate the saturated measurement, and moves on.

Both of these processes are consistent with the data we have, but they are different processes, and they yield different confidence intervals. Process 2 is the one we would prefer as statisticians. If the voltages are often well above 100V, Process 1 has a potentially catastrophic failure mode in which the measurements are occasionally severely underestimated, because the data are censored without our knowing it. The confidence interval will widen accordingly. We could mitigate this by asking the engineer to tell us when his 1000V meter is not working, but this is really just another way of ensuring that our data conforms to Process 2.

If the horse has already left the barn and we cannot determine when the measurements are and aren't censored, we could try to infer from the data the times when the 1000V meter isn't working. By introducing an inference rule into the process, we effectively create a new Process 1.5 distinct from both 1 and 2. Our inference rule would sometimes work and sometimes not, so the confidence interval from Process 1.5 would be intermediate in size compared to Processes 1 and 2.

In theory, there is nothing wrong or suspicious about a single statistic having three different confidence intervals associated with three different plausibly representative stochastic processes. In practice, few consumers of statistics *want* three different confidence intervals. They want one, the one that is based on *what would have actually happened, had the experiment been repeated many times.* So typically, the applied statistician considers the domain knowledge she has acquired during the project, makes an educated guess, and presents the confidence interval associated with the process she has guessed. Or she works with the customer to formalize the process, so there's no need to guess going forward.

## How to Respond to New Information

Despite the insistence of the statistician in the story, frequentist inference does not require that we repeat measurements when we gain new information suggesting the generating stochastic process is not quite what we originally conceived. However, if the process is going to be repeated, we do need to ensure that all repetitions are consistent with the model process assumed by the confidence interval. We can do this by changing the process or by changing our model of it.

If we change the process, we may need to discard past data which was collected inconsistently with that process. But that isn't an issue here, because all the process variations we're considering are only different when some of the data is above 100V, and that never happened in this case.

Whatever we do, model and reality must be brought into alignment. Only then will the theoretically guaranteed frequentist error rate be what the customer actually gets upon repeated performance of the process.

## The Bayesian Alternative

On the other hand, if all we really care about is the probable range of the true mean for *this* sample, we should cast aside frequentism entirely and seek out the people who sell the answer to that question - the Bayesians. If we go this route, all the haggling over counterfactuals becomes irrelevant; all that matters is the prior and likelihood. In exchange for this simplification, we lose any hope of guaranteeing an error rate under repeated performance of the "experiment".

## Why the Fuss?

This story was constructed to make it look like the frequentist statistician fusses over silly things for no reason. *Honestly, who cares about these silly counterfactuals?* The answer, of course, is that ***everyone should care.*** Vitally important scientific fields are currently suffering from a serious [replication crisis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replication_crisis), which suggests the frequency of false discoveries is much higher than expected in the scientific literature. One of the drivers of this crisis, although [not the only one by any means](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/research/unpublished/p_hacking.pdf), is the rise of [p-hacking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_dredging), which is when researchers play with many variations of a model, controlling for different variables, until they get significance.

P-hacking has been extensively vilified in the popular scientific media and the blogosphere, but few actually understand what is wrong about p-hacking and why. Contrary to popular statistical opinion, there is nothing wrong with looking at your data before, during, and after the modeling process. What is wrong is failing to report exploratory analyses and how they influenced the course of the study. Only by looking at the full process can we even possibly determine what stochastic model is representative of that process and what frequentist analysis is appropriate for that model, if any.

Claiming that a certain frequentist analysis is appropriate is a very serious claim. Making that claim implies that you are binding yourself to the discipline of the stochastic process you have chosen, which entails an entire system of counterfactuals about what you would have done in different situations. You have to actually conform to that system for the frequentist guarantee to apply to you. Very few researchers, especially those in fields that emphasize open-ended exploration, conform to the system, and they do not report their deviations scrupulously; that is why we now have a replication crisis on our hands. (Some respected researchers have argued that this expectation is unrealistic, a position I sympathize with, but that is getting beyond the scope of this post.)

> It might seem unfair that we are criticizing published papers based on a claim about what they would have done had the data been different. But this is the (somewhat paradoxical) nature of frequentist reasoning: if you accept the concept of the p-value, you have to respect the legitimacy of modeling what would have been done under alternative data. [(Gelman & Loken, 2013)](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/research/unpublished/p_hacking.pdf)

In studies that are relatively simple and/or standardized, such as clinical trials, we can adjust for things like multiple or sequential comparisons and maintain the theoretical error rate; in more complex and exploratory studies, a frequentist model may be inapplicable because the researcher may not be [fully conscious of all the decisions being made](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/research/unpublished/p_hacking.pdf), let alone recording and presenting them explicitly. In such cases, the researcher should (1) be honest and upfront about what was done; (2) present p-values either with strong caveats, or not at all; (3) consider presenting other lines of evidence, such as prior plausibility of the hypothesis or a follow-up replication study.

Comment: This looks like a good answer but I'll need to mentally digest it sometime tomorrow.

Comment: by description of the problem as stated it sounds as if an engineer is claiming that he was always doing your option #2

Comment: Perhaps, but he didn't say so explicitly. Large errors can be made when people guess what other people are thinking rather than discussing explicitly.

Comment: In applied statistics courses, too little emphasis is given to the formalism of what it means to estimate parameters.  Suppose we plan to toss a coin, and record the frequency of heads.   Going in, we tacitly assume the actual distribution is Bernoulli with p=q=0.5.  The, after 1,000 flips, we ask ourselves 'how likely is it this was a fair coin' by comparing reality to the theory/assumption.  But in much science, people assume things are normally distributed, then use t-tests.  But those are meaningless if the returns aren't normally distributed.

Answer (score 1):

There seems a logical fallacy.  Whether or not the 1000 volt meter was working, the engineer says "if any readings would have been over 100, I would have used the other meter."  But how would he know that the voltage was >100 without having used the 1000 volt meter?

I don't think this puzzle is well-enough formulated to make for a useful philosophical question.  Practically, I agree with the answer that the right thing is to make a histogram and see if it looks truncated.

But, in any case, nothing in the question deals with the issues that matter, like: (1) what is the known (or suspected) distribution of readings, and why?  Is there some reason to believe they are normally distributed?  (2) If that question is not answered, then how was any confidence interval ever estimated?

To take it to an extreme, some 'voltage' is being measured. Suppose the power supply can't deliver more than 100 volts.  Were that true, presumably there couldn't be any measurements over 100 volts, so the meter is irrelevant.

There is a whole bunch more - in terms of priors, constraints, etc. - that goes into estimation and the like than the question covers.  This is unlike the 'Monty Hall' paradox, which is crisp and clean.

Comment: The point of the story is to critique interpretations of probability that rely on hypothetical events by extending these interpretations to an absurd extreme. The issues you mention are beside the point. Supposedly the engineer would have known to change voltmeters if needed (e.g. sees a reading of "100") and the statistician otherwise has reasons to use the approach he is using (e.g. he just so happens to already know that the normal distribution is a good model for these readings).